# How to add a TImeStamp for the Accelerometer Sensor Reading?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appcompat

I have created a sensor readings in my android application with kotlin. But I want to implement a TimeStamp to notice the timings for every event change in sensors.
Could anyone help me please?

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),SensorEventListener {
private lateinit var mSensorManager: SensorManager
private var mAccelerometer : Sensor ?=null
private var resume = false
private lateinit var square: TextView

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)


    mSensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)

}

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
    if(event != null && resume){
        if(event?.sensor?.type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

            val sides = event.values[0]
            val upDown = event.values[1]

            square = findViewById(R.id.sensor_value)
            square.apply{
                rotationX = upDown * 3f
                rotationY = sides * 3f
                rotation = -sides
                translationX = sides * -10
                translationY = upDown * 10



                /*
         // set reference times
         if (sensorTimeReference === 0L && myTimeReference === 0L) {
             sensorTimeReference = event.timestamp
             myTimeReference = System.currentTimeMillis()
         }
         // set event timestamp to current time in milliseconds
         event.timestamp = myTimeReference +
                 Math.round((event.timestamp - sensorTimeReference) / 1000000.0)
         // some code... */
            }

            val color = if(upDown.toInt() == 0 && sides.toInt() == 0) Color.GREEN else Color.WHITE
            square.setBackgroundColor(color)

            square.text = "Accelerometer readings \n\n up/down  ${upDown.toInt()}\nleft/right ${sides.toInt()} \n "
        }
    }

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
}
override fun onPause(){
    super.onPause()
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
}

fun resumeReading(view: View){
    this.resume = true
}

fun pauseReading(view: View){
    this.resume = false
}


override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
   return
}


override fun onDestroy(){
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

}